# Get nth row of groups and fill with 'None' if row is missing

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df:

```
   a  b  c
1  2  3  6
2  2  5  7
3  4  6  8
```

I want every nth row of groupby a:

```
w=df.groupby('a').nth(0) #first row
x=df.groupby('a').nth(1)  #second row
```

The second group of the df has no second row, in this case I want to have 'None' values.

```
[In:] df.groupby('a').nth(1)
[Out:]

  a    b    c
1 2    5    7
2 None None None
```

Or maybe simplier: 
The df has 1-4 rows within groups. If a group has less than 4 rows, I want to extend the group, so that it has 4 rows and fill the missing rows with 'None'. Afterwards if I pick the nth row of groups, I have the desired output.

Answer (score 1):

If you are just interested in a specific `nth` but not have enough rows in some groups, you can consider to use `reindex` with `unique` value from the column a like:

```
print (df.groupby('a').nth(1).reindex(df['a'].unique()).reset_index())
   a    b    c
0  2  5.0  7.0
1  4  NaN  NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to assign a count/rank column and reindex/stack:

```
n=2
(df.assign(rank=df.groupby('a').cumcount())
   .query(f'rank < @n')
   .set_index(['a','rank'])
   .unstack('rank')
   .stack('rank', dropna=False)
   .reset_index()
   .drop('rank', axis=1)      
)
```

Output:

```
   a    b    c
0  2  3.0  6.0
1  2  5.0  7.0
2  4  6.0  8.0
3  4  NaN  NaN
```